# How do I change directories from the command line?

Tags: command-line, directory, home-directory, cd-command

I'm try to change to my Desktop directory from the terminal.

Running

```
cd /home/desktop
```

gives an error in the terminal saying no directory found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: [Downloaded a program to my home/downloads folder and can't access it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425574/downloaded-a-program-to-my-home-downloads-folder-and-cant-access-it)

Answer (score 7):

[iBelieve's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/335005/527764) covers almost everything, but alternatively you can type

```
cd ~/Desktop/
```

the `~/` stands for `/home/$USER/` or `$HOME/`

Comment: +1 for mentioning the tilde-home shortcut.  Although it stands for /home/<username>/.

Comment: <username> disappeared so I changed it to [username]

Comment: Home also needs to be lowercase, and you can use html escapes to get the < and > symbols to appear (I edited to demonstrate)

Comment: You too: $USER is easier ;-) (it will automatically transform to the current user)

Comment: Or `$HOME` too.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question mentioned in the quoted article:

The directory format is like this:

```
/
    home
        <username>
            Desktop
            Documents
            ...
```

so your command should be

```
cd /home/$USER/Desktop
```

To learn the directory structure, I'd suggest opening up the Home Folder app from the launcher on the left, and going to Computer and just exploring for a while. You won't be able to break anything outside of your home folder.

Comment: $USER is easier ;-) (it will automatically transform to the current user)

Answer (score 5):

Because I haven't seen it mentioned yet, it should be noted that all directory names in Ubuntu (Linux) are case-sensitive.  So even if you were in your correct home directory, executing a `cd desktop` should and will fail.  If you look at [@iBelieve's post](https://askubuntu.com/a/335005/527764), you can see that the `Desktop` directory starts with a capital 'D'.  To get there, you will need to  specify the correct case.

```
cd Desktop
```

To help you in the future, take a look at this [Ubuntu help wiki page on using the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal).

Answer (score 1):

The following bash builtin commands are equivalent and they change the current working directory to your Desktop directory from your user home directory:

```bsh
cd ~/Desktop               # my favorite

cd ~; cd Desktop

cd ~ && cd Desktop

cd $HOME/Desktop

cd /home/$USER/Desktop

cd /home/username/Desktop  # where 'username' is your user name

cd $CDPATH && cd Desktop

cd `locate -b '\Desktop'`

cd $(locate -b '\Desktop')
```