# Downloaded a program to my home/downloads folder and can't access it

Tags: command-line, software-installation, directory

I have already installed Apache OpenOffice 4.0.0 and would like to update it to the newer version which is Apache OpenOffice 4.0.1.

I have already downloaded the `_deb.tar.cz` files that were required but I can't seem to access the download through the terminal to install it.

What I tried was to open the Home/ directory but it can't seem to find it using the command:

```
cd /home/downloads/apache
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the default LibreOffice? this is available form the Software Center and therefore much easier to use. If you do wish to do a manual installation I advise you to look for a .deb installation package since that is the Ubunut (debian) native package format.

Comment: I agree with bacon: it is usually best to use software from the repository (for example, installed with the Software Center). You can be sure it will work with your version of Ubuntu and you'll get updates automatically.

Comment: Related: [How do I change directories from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335004/how-do-i-change-directories-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

Go into the downloads folder and extract the tar.gz file by running,

```
cd /home/$USER/Downloads
```

OR

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz
```

The above command extracts the .deb file inside Downloads directory.Then run the below command to install .deb file,

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

The `D` in downloads is a capital, so you need to enter

```
cd /home/user-name/Downloads
```

here `user-name` should be replaced with your user name, or you can use:

```
cd /home/$USER/Downloads
```

or

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Understand the directory structure of Ubuntu (and Linux in general)

your `Home` directory as shown in nautilus is actually `/home/user-name`.